# How to truncate columns overflow in excel?

Tags: excel

I have a table in excel

```
id  name    salary
1   mike milovski
2   anna
3   alex abraham mcdonald
4   pete s. 100
```

The `salary` filed is not always filled out . It is null in many cases . E.g. in the above sample it is filled out only for row 4. Whenever it is null ,  the values from the `name` field overflow (overlap) and  `visually` it looks like they are on the `salary` field. How can **I truncate this visual effect ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three methods:

1. Format the cell as "wrap text".  You may want to adjust the row height after if you applied this after making the entry.
2. Put a non-printing character (e.g. space; alt-0160;) in the salary cell
3. Format the cell as "shrink to fit".